# defective kml file?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have written a program that writes kml files that display well in Google Earth, but when I try them on Google Maps, they malfunction often. They have passed feed validator and other checkers, but when I click the placemark,  I get an empty address: popup, and fly to lat 0, long 0, off the African coast. I have stripped out everything, and am left with:

```
<?xml   version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
    xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document  id="DOC1">
    <name>sample memberships Kml File</name>
    <open>1</open>
        <description>remove xmlns gx</description>
    <Folder id="FLD1">
        <name>BusinessMembers</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <description>BluePushpin</description>
        <Placemark id="PMA">
            <name>A member</name>
            <open>1</open>
            <address>Fayette County</address>
                <description>a</description>
            <Point id="PTA">
                <coordinates>-84.41593,37.916132</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I cannot see anything wrong with this. The file is fetched from Google sites.

Anybody see something I don't ?

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the address element, it's not supported in Google Maps. Here's a list of supported elements: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps

Comment: No, removing address, and promoting description to direct child of placemark does not help. 
The bad behavior seems to have something with where the icon is clicked (near the top), or when the item in the left list is clicked.
Thanks for the page ref, I will read and think, tomorrow.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, can you post a live running version of the file you're having trouble with so we can see the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem.  Here's a [link to my custom kmz](http://goo.gl/maps/dIwF).  Clicking on the links in the left **should** open a popup with that route's elevation information, but instead throws me to 0,0 with an empty address popup.  It's not consistent either; sometimes it works, but usually doesn't.